# rref matrix equations - k2 7

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is about reduced row echelon form, Gauss-Jordan, inverting matrices, and solving systems of equations.

I try to solve a system of equations with matrices. I know what operations are allowed, but I just seem to arrive at the wrong conclusion 50 % of the times. So here are three problems, each with my calculation. My hope is to clarify if I:

- am making a careless misstake, and where those mistakes are (if so, I may have to do these problems in a slower pace)
- do not know the theory well enough (don't make the correct steps)
- use a bad or "not smart" way of attacking the problem. (for example, if I do *row1 + row2* when I shoul have taken *row1 - row3*).

$$\begin{align} x_1 + ax^2 + x_3 & = 3 \\ \\
3x_1 + (3a + 1)x_2 + 3x_3 & = 5 \\ \\
2x_1 + 2ax_2 + a^2x_3 & = 5\end{align}$$
solution: see picture below.

I say $x_3=-\frac{1}{a^2-2}$ while the book says $x_3=-a^2-2$

[image: pb3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & 1 & 3 \\3 & 3 a + 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 2a & a^2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

We get a RREF of:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 3 + 7 a + \dfrac{1}{a^2 - 2}\\0 & 1 & 0 & -7 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{2-a^2} \end{bmatrix}$$

You got the last two rows spot on (at the top of your page $2$), but for Row $3$, you should divide by $a^2-2$, while noting the problem area.

You just need to use these correct rows and rework Row 1 as something went south there.

Comment: Deserves a TU! +1

Comment: Indeed, it hasn't exactly been beautiful *weather* here in Wisconsin, but I've done my darned-est to make the *day* beautiful, anyway!

Comment: How true that is! Hope yours has been beautiful!

Comment: @jacob: Did this resolve your issues?